# Geometric distribution with different probability for each trial

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I have $3f+1$ balls, $f$ are black and $2f+1$ are white.
First I choose a random ball, this is the first trial. I continue to draw $f+1$ balls, meaning I have at least one white ball.

My question is, how to calculate the following distribution $X$, such that $P(X = k)$ means what is the probability that the first $k-1$ balls are black, and the $k$-th ball is white.

Comment: While repeatedly flipping a coin, each trial is independent and would follow the geometric distribution, here the events are dependent on one another.  Rather than a geometric distribution, the name for what is going on here is [Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  Find the probability that within the first $k-1$ trials they all resulted in black, followed by getting a white ball afterwards.

Comment: Long overdue, but your comment helped me get the correct answer. Thank you!